# Saving an address to the first location in an observableCollection?

Tags: c#, wpf, observablecollection

I have an ObservableCollection named AddressList of Addresses.I populate the AdddressList with
addresses in a method called CreateAddressBinding. An address have different properties and one of them is IsDefault. For one of the addresses this property is true and false for the rest of them. I am trying to assign the Default address, which would have IsDefault property of the address true to the first location of the AddressList.

Some of the Code:

```
     foreach (var address in Addresses)
        {

            AddressList.Add(address);
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
foreach(var address in Addresses)
{
    if(address.IsDefault)
    {
        AddressList.Insert(0, address);
        continue;
    }
    AddressList.Add(address);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add all but the `IsDefault` address in the `foreach` loop and then add the `IsDefault` as the first item.

try

```
foreach (var address in Addresses)
{
    if(!address.IsDefault)
    {
        AddressList.Add(address);
    }
}
AddressList.InsertItem(0, Addresses.Where(x => x.IsDefault).ToList()[0]);
```

Comment: I am not sitting the IsDefault to true for the first one, I want to save the one with IsDefault=true on the first location, that is AddressList[0].

Comment: Sorry misunderstood the question the above answer should work.

Answer (score 0):

A nice way is to create a property to access to the default address. Here is an example if the addresses are for a user.

```
public class User
{
    public ObservableCollection<Address> Addresses;

    public Address DefaultAddress
    {
        get
        {
            return Addresses.Single(a => a.IsDefault);
        }
        set
        {
            Addresses.Remove(DefaultAddress);
            Addresses.Insert(0, value);
        }
    }
}
```

This will add the default address at the top of the collection.